# form submit without refreshing page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

i have old code, that has jquery v1.9.
now for some new edit, i need to submit form without refreshing page using ajax. but it dose not work.
and when i change version of jquery, old script dose not work.
my code is here:
days.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#formSubmit').click(function(){
$.post("day2.php",
{name: $('#name').val()},
    function(data){
    $('#response').html(data);}         
);});});
</script>   
<div>
<input type="text" id="name">
<button id="formSubmit">send</button>
<textarea id="response"></textarea>
</div>
```

and day2.php:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "response: " +$name;
```

i dont know where is problem!

Comment: String Concatenation in PHP is `.` not `+`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo "response: " . $name;
```

instead of:

```
echo "response: " +$name;
```

Comment: Also answering typo questions won't help future visitors. It's best to flag the questions when you have more rep

Comment: @Nikoo please right click on page > `Console` tab and send here the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is in second file where in

```
echo "response: " +$name;
```

you have used + as string concatenation operator instead of '.'

so actual code is like this

```
echo "response: " .$name;
```